# Determine the number of ways to choose $a_i$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Let $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^{n} \in \{ -1,1\}$ be $n$ numbers, each either $-1$ or $1$. Find the number of ways such that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \geq 0 \ \forall \ 1 \leq k \leq n $$

The number of $1$ should be greater than or equal to $-1$, but the restriction that it is so for all $k$ is creating some trouble.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand phrase "but the restriction that it is so for all $k$ is creating trouble".

Comment: Those are 'bounded random walks'

Comment: A lot of formulas and references can be found at [A001405](https://oeis.org/A001405).

Comment: @ColeStiegler Not quite. Closely related though.

Comment: @ColeStiegler I already posted the correct sequence in a comment above.

Comment: I see the difference, thank you.

Comment: @Xpw It means that 1s will be equal to or greater than for all sequences of $a_i$ from 1 to n. For example (1, -1, 1, 1) is allowed, but (1,-1,-1,1) is not allowed.

Comment: @orlp Can you please write that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

This sequence is OEIS [A001405](https://oeis.org/A001405), where you can find a lot of references, equivalences and formulas for it.

Answer (score 1):

orlp's answer is right on. Here's a visual aid:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/So54f.jpg)